# Does delegated authenticaton work for high volume portal users?

Tags: delegated-authentication

We are currently building a force.com site with high volume portal user license. We would like to use single signon where we currently have an external webservice authenticating the login information from an active directory.

1. Can we enable DA (Delegated Authentication) on the portal so that users can be authenticated using this webservice?
2. We want to build our own home page with login control. I was told that with DA , a login page is not customizable.Is this right?
3. Can you send me some links where it confirms delegated authentication is possible using high volume portal license?

Answer (score 1):

Portals can only use federated (SAML-based) authentication.

[Enabling SSO for portals](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_portals.htm)

[Best practices for implementing SSO](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sso_tips.htm)

It's quite easy to use SAML-based authentication with Active Directory and Salesforce. Perhaps federated authentication is a better option for you?

**There is another way though**. You can expose the [Apex system methods for customer portal registration and login](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites) through a public Force.com Sites page. This way you can roll-your-own "delegated authentication" by passing this information to the Force.com Sites page through URL parameters.

Comment: @wesnoite Thanks for your reply. My client is a federal agency and has issues in purchasing an idp for saml at this point. Is there any other option other than saml at this point?

Comment: Ah, there'd be a lot of red tape! Federated authentication is your only options unfortunately, and in salesforce-speak this means SAML. ADFS is an excellent solution if you can influence them.

Comment: I just remembered an implementation that provides another option. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Noite  Your point is well taken. I am trying that option and see if it would work for us. Just a basic question. Do i need a customer portal enabled to setup a force.com site for authenticated user license?

Comment: Yes, the authenticated portal user is a type of customer portal user.